# Sqlite ADO.NET Entity Framework 3.5 ASP.NET MVC Simple Example "Race Condition"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sqlite

I have this simple example where I am trying to create a spike using ASP.NET MVC 1, Sqlite, and ADO.NET Entity Framework as I need a portable datastore (DB) that can run on .NET 3.5

I have my simple spike working (saving, deleting, modifying records) however I just noticed something strange.  I am using an extremely simple Repository pattern in order to manipulate the data.

If you run the site it shows a new record is created.  However I noticed that if I refresh too quickly (hold down F5 for example in the browser to replicate) it will throw the exception below.

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

I feel this is clearly a concurrency issue with the way my Index action is saving/deleting the records for my test.  How can I modify my Repository so that I can still utilize this pattern (which I like and think is fairly clean) yet also prevent this race condition?  I went ahead and zipped up the solution below which should work out of the box (Visual Studio 2008)

http://andrewherrick.com/spike/SqliteMVC1EF.zip